# My Homestead reset when i restart my machine

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I'm facing a problem that everytime i restart my machine homestead reset, i mean when i ssh to my box, i can't find the directories in the development directory

I mean that i find the directories on my machine but when i ssh to homestead i can't find them

i tried to run `homestead provision` but nothing changed, still can link between my machine and the virtual box

you see below that i have `laravel` directory linked to my current box code\laravel

My setup like that

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/code
  to:  /home/vagrant/code

 sites:
- map: laravel.app
  to: /home/vagrant/code/laravel/public

databases:
- homestead


variables:
- key: APP_ENV
  value: local
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds annoying. Have you tried using `vagrant reload` instead?

In case you know when you're going to shut down your computer (not when low battery is forcing a shutdown) you can save your vagrant box's state by doing `vagrant suspend` and after boot: `vagrant resume`.

Hope this works for you.